# Do Android zip files really take so much space when expanded?

Tags: java, android, zip

Apologies if this is a naive question, but I can't seem to find a good answer to my question:

I see some of the custom ROMS average around 300MB.  However, when the ROM installs, the amount of space taken goes to around 7GB.  Formatting, cache wiping, etc have been done before install.  I simply can not believe that zipping algorithm is so efficient.  I am used to seeing 2:1, 3:1 efficiency ratios.  Are zippers really that efficient these days?

Same story with installing Android apps:
the install file, let's say 45mb.  Available space before install is let's say 10GB.  then after install available size would go down 9.5GB (ie 500MB used), but the App Info would say that only 56MB were taken from the system.

Anyone knows how to interpret above?

Comment: Compiled code can be highly repetitive, more so than just any binary data.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, are zipped files actually uncompileed installers?  I thought those were compressed files and nothing more